# Google+ - Sharing interactive posts from wpf

Tags: wpf, google-plus

This link: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive
explain how to create a share button in web sites.

I am working on wpf application and want the same behavior as facebook's [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), which is similar to Sharing interactive posts in google+.

I just want to skip the stage of clicking the share button, and just open a browser with the share offer.

any ideas?

Comment: could you just navigate to it in a frame

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the [share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink), which you can use via a link, the [interactive post button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) does not currently offer you the ability to link to the dialog or launch it with JavaScript.